# Не срабатывает слушатель LocationListener

Tags: android, android-location

Я создаю `LocationListener` и регистрирую его в `LocationManager` для получения изменений в местоположении, но возникает проблема: в методы слушателя не приходят ответы! Совсем! Вот код создания:

```
        LocationListener listener = new LocationListener() {
            @Override
            public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
                if (lastLocation == null) {
                    lastLocation = location;
                }

                distanceInMeters += location.distanceTo(lastLocation);
                lastLocation = location;

                Log.i(TAG, "LocationChanged");
            }

            @Override
            public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
                Log.i(TAG, "StatusChanged");
            }

            @Override
            public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
                Log.i(TAG, "ProviderEnabled");
            }

            @Override
            public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
                Log.i(TAG, "ProviderDisabled");
            }
        };

        LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED &&
                ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION)
                != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

            Log.i(TAG, "FCK...");
            return;
        }

        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(locationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,
                1000,
                1,
                listener);
```

Почему не срабатывает слушатель и как это исправить?

P.S. GPS - включил.

Comment: вы дебажили, доходит ли до вызова requestLocationUpdates?

Comment: @YuryPashkov, к счастью (или сожалению) — доходит.

Comment: По коду все верно вроде бы. На другом девайсе не пробовали тестить, просто gps "прогреться" нужно, чтоб координаты начали приходить, иногда это может и 5 минут занимать. А в манифесте тоже все в порядке?

Comment: @YuryPashkov, сейчас запущу и подожду (хотя какие нафиг 5 минут, сразу же должно работать, это жесткий косяк от разработчиков), в манифесте разрешение есть `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>`, а другого девайся нет...

Comment: @YuryPashkov, уху! Пришел ответ! Правда `onProviderDisabled`...

Comment: Значит не до конца включен)) А вообще с gps это нормально, у него просто есть холодный и горячий старт, вот когда происходит холодный, то приходится ждать долго.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для GPS добавьте permission `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>` 
**ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION** - по вышкам сотовым
 **ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION** - gps

Comment: Заработало! Пойду про разрешение почитаю, про него в книге не слова...

Comment: А Вы не перепутали? Может `coarse` по вышкам? У меня заработало только с ним, а  я сижу с моб. интернета. Да и гугл доки пишут, что `coarse` - это приблизительное местоположение (что, по смыслу, должно быть свойственно для симок), а `fine` - точное. Это как-то не логично, да и названия странные (при переводе ключевых слов у меня не вышло извлечь смысл без документации).